# Using data attributes in css before/after for a background image

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

So I have HTML markup that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" data-icon="data:image/png;base64,iVKAInsdal...">Some link</a>
```

Then I want to use that `data-icon` in my CSS to display as the base 64 background image. Something like:

```
a:before {
    content: "";
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    background: url(attr(data-icon)); // this doesn't work
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: not with css. But we can do with jquery. Do you want that?

Comment: Could you not use `content: attr(data-icon);`?

Comment: Thank you. I'll be able to get it working with jQuery. I just wanted to see if it's possible with CSS.

Comment: @BeatAlex, that only works for text content, not data-uri base 64 images. I should've mentioned that in the post.

Comment: It IS possible with CSS, see my revised answer below...just not how you may have thought

Answer (score 16):

### [This IS possible!](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/TVre9/1/)

(but not how you may think)

```
a{
    background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRrlZZQ3MwNcconkIeLX3_nS_IV81gJ8rincQsipqXGsiBkPmCX);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:1000px 1000px;
}

a:before {
    content: '';
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    background-image: inherit;
    background-position:0px 0px;
}
```

Unfortunately what you are attempting to do will not work, `attr` is only applicable to the `content` property.

The only possible alternative would be to give the parent a background image, then set `background-image` on the pseudo element to `inherit`. If you set the parent elements `background-position` outside its boundaries then the psuedo elements to zero, it will give the same effect of no image on the parent, but an image on the psuedo.

Comment: This is pretty clever!

Comment: @BeatAlex...not infallible and has its downsides, but the only way I could think of almost accomplishing what the OP was after

Comment: You need to change `content:` to `content:'';` :) +1 for this too

Comment: Definitely very clever :) I need it do be unique icons. I have a list of links like that and each have their own icon I'd like to display. I think I need to find another way. Thank you thought - pretty slick!

Comment: It will still work...just set background image inline instead of your data attribute: **http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/TVre9/2/**  this will accomplish the same thing without being constrained to setting images in your CSS

Comment: Right, but I'm getting the HTML and data-icon stuff back from a server. I'd need to use jQuery to manipulate it. Just wanted to see if I can do it with CSS and no jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
content: attr(data-icon);
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/EyDJx/)

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQHzy/)

This will only work for text based `data` attributes though and not images.

You can apply a normal background, but only `content` allows `attr`.

Comment: Look at SW4's answer, he's nailed it. @dmathisen

Comment: it only working for text and not working to display image