# HTML ul list item, pass image src for each li using attribute

Tags: html, css

I want to display each flag for each country in my ul list items.

Here is my code I tried

```css
ul li {
     list-style: none;
     height: 34px; line-height: 34px;
     padding-left: 46px;
    }

    ul li::before {
     position: absolute;
     background-image: url(attr(flag));
        background-size: 30px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        left: 10px; margin-top: 6px;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        content:"";
    }
```

```html
<ul class="select-box" id="slcCountry">
    <li flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg">AFG</li>
    <li flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg">ALA</li>
    <li flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg">ALB</li>
</ul>
```

It does not work for me. How I can solve please.

Comment: I think you have to add `data-` to your attribute (so make it `data-flag=".."`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using data attributes in css before/after for a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816065/using-data-attributes-in-css-before-after-for-a-background-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flag` is not a valid attribute and you can target the list item by using an inline style and targeting the element that way. No need for pseudo elements in this instance. This should do the trick.

```
<ul class="select-box" id="slcCountry">
    <li style="background-image: url('https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg');">AFG</li>
    <li style="background-image: url('https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg');">ALA</li>
    <li style="background-image: url('https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg');">ALB</li>
</ul>
```

```
ul li {
    background-image: none; /* used as a fallback */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0 0 0 46px;
}
```

Comment: I think it is possible, watch the example on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Comment: Yes but that requires `data-flag` to be used, `flag` as is doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add image tag like

```
<ul class="select-box" id="slcCountry">
    <li><img src="https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg"/>AFG</li>
    <li><img src="https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg"/>ALA</li>
    <li><img src="https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg"/>ALB</li>
</ul>

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    height: 34px; line-height: 34px;
    padding-left: 46px;
}

ul li img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px; margin-top: 6px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `attr()` only works for `content` property of css pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`.

> **As MDN says:**
>
> *[The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than content is experimental.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)*

So using it with `background-image` will make it invalid...If you are not allowed to change the html part, you will need to add some jQuery.

```js
$(".select-box li").each(function() {
  $(this).append("<img src=" + $(this).attr("flag") + ">")
})
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding-left: 46px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li img {
  max-width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="select-box" id="slcCountry">
  <li flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg">AFG</li>
  <li flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg">ALA</li>
  <li flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg">ALB</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you for explaining, if may ask  
can i replace ul list into select tag? and this works same too?

Answer (score 0):

Another easy idea using CSS variables if you want to keep the use of pseudo element:

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding-left: 46px;
}

ul li::before {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: var(--i);
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<ul class="select-box" id="slcCountry">
  <li style="--i:url(https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg)">AFG</li>
  <li style="--i:url(https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg)">ALA</li>
  <li style="--i:url(https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg)">ALB</li>
</ul>
```