# Display image using attr in HTML select element

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-select

I want to display each country's flag in select options.
Here is my code i tried:

```
<select id="slcCountry">
    <option flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg">AFG</option>
    <option flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg">ALA</option>
    <option flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg">ALB</option>
</select>
```

Here is css to show the image

```
select option {
    background-image: url(attr(flag));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px;
    background-position: 10px 6px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 34px;
}
```

How I can display each image (flag) of the list here. Help me please.

Comment: inline style? <option style="background:url(your-flag)">AFG</option>

Comment: this is nearly the same as you just asked here a couple of minutes ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665907/html-ul-list-item-pass-image-src-for-each-li-using-attribute 
Flag is not a valid attribute. Use images for this.

Comment: @cloned nice catch.

Comment: @cloned i need solution, posts i created are not same, first one was ul list items, and this post about select element

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508029/dropdown-select-with-images?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @MohamudNeeri see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing ,for custom attribute use html5 [data attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) instead of flag attr (not valid html, ),

It will not be easy or possible to implement this with simple select , so Using plugin and with some css/ js trick will be possible ,

I've used [bootstrap select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) , with bootstrap 3 and jquery , the result is below :

See below snippet :

```js
$(function() {

  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    size: 4
  });
  // selector for generated dropdonw button
  var $button = $("button[data-id='slcCountry']");
  //generate img for each selectpicker option 
  $("#slcCountry option").each(function(i, el) {
    var flag = $(el).data("flag");
    if (flag)
      $button.next().find("li[data-original-index=" + i + "] a").css("background-image", "url(" + flag + ")");

  });


  //cahnge event to assign icon to selected elmen t
  $("#slcCountry").on("change", function(e) {
    var flag = $("#slcCountry option:selected").data("flag");
    if (flag)
      $button.find(".filter-option").css("background-image", "url(" + flag + ")");
    else
      $button.find(".filter-option").css("background-image", "url('')")
  });

  $('.selectpicker').trigger('change');

});
```

```css
#img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.dropdown-menu ul li a,
button[data-id='slcCountry'] .filter-option {
  background-size: 25px;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" id="slcCountry">

    <option data-flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg">AFG</option>
    <option data-flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/dza.svg">DZA</option>
    <option data-flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg">ALB</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hope this will fix your issue ?

Comment: yes, it works for me, thank you.. but bootstrap changed my page style, can i ignore it? or maybe write related css rules for this select element?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using jquery:

Please note that The code snippet may not work because :

1. setting background for option element is not supported on major webkit browsers. For more methods to put image in options, refer to this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list):
2. your images are hosted on `https`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("option[flag]").each(function(){
    $(this).css("background-image","url('"+ $(this).attr("flag") +"')");
  })

})
```

```css
select option {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px;
    background-position: 10px 6px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="slcCountry">
    <option flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg">AFG</option>
    <option flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg">ALA</option>
    <option flag="https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg">ALB</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that won't work on most browsers. you can only set `background-color` and `color` for select options for webkit browsers

Comment: Also won't work on mobile devices since they don't allow styling select options as well

Comment: `the code snippet may not work because` ... it won't work, it's not because https ...